# How to delete the rows from azure table using powershell script

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I want to delete the records from azure storage table based on some condtion. I have column like datemodified in azure storage table. 
My query will looks like

```
datemodifed < (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddDays(-10)
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove the records one by one based on above condition using powershell script. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
$entityToDelete | Remove-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable
```

To get the $cloudTable you need to get the storage account's and entity's context first.
For example you can use this script:

```
$storageAccountName = "MyStorage"
$resourceGroup = "MyRG"
$tableName = "MyTable"
$columnName = "MyColum"
$value = "EntityValueToSearch"

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Name $storageAccountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context 

$storageTable = Get-AzStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $ctx
$cloudTable = ($storageTable).CloudTable

[string]$filter = `
  [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition($columnName,`
  [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal,$value)

# Get entity
$entityToDelete = Get-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -customFilter $filter

$entityToDelete | Remove-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable
```

For more info and a good referance:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#deleting-table-entities

Answer (score -1):

[Working with Azure Storage Tables from PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/paulomarques/2017/01/17/working-with-azure-storage-tables-from-powershell/)

[Windows Azure Storage Cmdlets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Microsoft-Azure-Storage-Cmdlets)

TableOperation.Delete accepts a Table Entity. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.delete.aspx

Look into TableQuery class here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery_methods.aspx

Reference :https://www.wintellect.com/deleting-entities-in-windows-azure-table-storage/